# Is this JS code a good way for defining class with private methods?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, access-modifiers

I was recently browsing a `open source` `JavaScript` project. The project is a straight port from another project in `C language`. It mostly use static methods, packed together in classes. Most classes are implemented using this pattern :

```
Foo = (function () {
    var privateField = "bar";
    var publicField = "bar";

    function publicMethod() 
    {
        console.log('this is public');
    }   

    function privateMethod() 
    {
        console.log('this is private');
    }

    return {  
        publicMethod : publicMethod,        
        publicField : publicField
    };
})();
```

This was the first time I saw private methods implemented that way. I perfectly understand how it works, using a anonymous method. Here is my question : **is this pattern a good practice ?** What are the actual limitations or caveats ? Usually i declare my JavaScript classes like that :

```
Foo = new function () {
    var privateField = "test";
    this.publicField = "test";

    this.publicMethod = function()
    {
        console.log('this method is public');
        privateMethod();
    }   

    function privateMethod()
    {
        console.log('this method is private');
    }       
};
```

Other than syntax, is there any difference with the pattern show above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form can be generalized like so:

```
A = (function() { return {}; })();
```

It gives us an object `A` with no explicit constructor. The object identifies exclusively as `Object` and the default `Object` constructor is used. Creating another object from `A`'s constructor yields an empty object:

```
var a_test = new A.constructor();
```

`a_test` will be an empty object (`{}`).

The 2nd form can be generalized like so:

```
B = new function() { /* whatever */ }
```

It gives an object `B` which is an instance of an anonymous function. It's constructor is defined, and we can create new instances like so:

```
var b_test = new B.constructor();
```

In this case, `b_test` will be identical to our original `B` object, private members and all.

**The first form prevents users from building replicas. The second form allows it.**

Comment: I did not know about the JS `constructor` keyword. Since the project I was taking a look use classes with only static methods (there is no reason to instantiate them) what they did is probably the best way. This is the equivalent of `static class` in `C#`

Comment: The advantage of using a labeled function constructor is that you can get the label via constructor.name. A little bit like a type but JS OOP is very different under the hood in terms of inheritance and the nature of how the public/private stuff works.